# DisconnectedContext was detected with XmlSerializer

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

I'm using XmlSerializer to deserialize the content of a file, using following line of code:-

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
```

But it gives me the following error and I'm unable to understand the reason for it:-

> DisconnectedContext was detected
>   Message: Context 0x77c698' is disconnected.  Releasing the interfaces from the current context (context 0x77c5e0).This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all contexts/apartments stay alive until the applicationis completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that liveinside them.

Kindly suggest probably what should be causing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just **ignore it**. It's an exception from the MDA. Just uncheck them from "monitored" exceptions or press F5 to ignore it.

Comment: @Adriano, would this be a good way of programming. Ignoring the exception?

Comment: To ignore exception **sometimes** may be necessary, moreover...running in debug inside VS you'll "see" many exception handled by Framework itself and things you probably don't need to worry about. In **general** exceptions shouldn't be ignored but the ones thrown and managed inside CLR are another story (for example I wouldn't worry for FileNotFoundException when loading assemblies)

Comment: @Adriano Thanks for your comments. I ignored the exception and now it is working fine. I was hoping of why that exception was occuring, but no matter.

Comment: I **suppose** it's a best practice to manage COM objects happily ignored by framework itself (when/how to release COM handles). Sorry I can't help more.